# How can I kill a php-fpm process without the signal being logged in the fpm log

Tags: php, logging, exec, kill, fpm

I have a function that through `exec()` kills a php-fpm process.

```
exec("kill -9 ".$pid);
```

Everytime I call it, a line gets added to the php-fpm log

```
WARNING: [pool xxxxxx] child 18120 exited on signal 9 (SIGKILL) after 308.956597 seconds from start
```

Is it possible to kill the process silently, without the signal being logged in the fpm log?
Thanks!

Comment: what is the problem to have the log file faithfully recording the events that have happened ?

Comment: @KenLee the problem is that the function gets called many times and it clogs up the log without adding any useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below solutions I think it will be work for you.:

```
kill -15 <PID>
```

Above was worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it still gets logged, except now it says `exited on signal 15`